# What is this Phone/Eye Icon in my notification bar on LG Volt?

Tags: lg, notification-icons

This icon appears seemingly at random, especially on my lock screen but not always. I can almost guarantee it pops up if I make a screenshot but I am not sure. I am on an LG Volt phone from Boost Mobile, and I was able to (finally) screenshot this icon after wondering about it for over a month.

A screenshot of the image is here: [image: http://imgur.com/OT9Mf9k]

Any guesses or preferably solid answers to what this could be are very much appreciated! It only appears for a brief moment (sometimes not even a second) before it disappears again.

I want to reiterate I see it most on my lock screen, but there could be other times it happens that I am not noticing.

Thank you in advance for your assistance in identifying what this is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icon seems to be some "user is active" icon that notifies you when the device captured you looking at the phone, but not *actively using* it.

There is a similar icon I know from my Samsung device that is meant to do this. It will prevent the display from becoming dark/locking the device so you can read your article, book etc. without tapping on the screen to keep it bright and unlocked.

If you like you may be able to disable that feature (active camera uses quite some battery) in the **Display** settings under **Smart Screen**.

Reference: [How to Enable Smart Screen on LG G2](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002135648/http://www.talkmob.com/2013/10/02/how-to-enable-smart-screen-on-lg-g2-753/)

Comment: Yes, this feature is like the "Smart Stay" feature on Galaxy S devices. Where it keeps the screen on while you are looking at the device.